# electronics design for residential water well systems

Tags: capacitor

Can you help with a question about residential water well systems? Does the capacitor effect water pressure? The pump motor runs constantly, but can only get about 20 lbs. pressure in pressure tank. Put 28 air pressure in tank ,& replaced pressure switch, but no change.

Comment: This question needs both more words and more illustrations. And quite likely a visit to the how to ask.

Comment: Probably your pump is failing.

Comment: Please, provide more data if you want someone to answer your question. Especially, don't limit yourself to what you think is the cause of your problem (the capacitor), but explain *in detail* what your real problem is (not enough pressure).

Comment: "Pressure Tank" is used to reduce pump cycling. Air pressure in that tank effects water volume per cycle. Pump and depth to the well water level effect "Pressure/Volume" of the output. The pump has to overcome "Head" pressure on starting/running.

Answer (score 1):

There are typically two capacitors on a split-phase motor. One is larger in value (maybe in the 100uF range) and is only used for starting the motor- it does not **a**ffect the motor torque once it is running. The other is used to effect a phase shift during normal operation- a change in capacitance of that capacitor (perhaps 10-20uF) **will** affect the run torque.

Of course there are other causes possible for a loss in pressure, but yes this is one. If you remove the run capacitor, carefully discharge it fully, and measure the capacitance it should be within the indicated tolerance (figure maybe +/-10% if the tolerance is not indicated).